# build 3d environment

Tags: ros, environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does any know how to build a 3d environment map?
for example : if i want to build my office's 3d environment "map" and use it in gazebo , put my robot in it and simulate, just like the things willow garage do. are there some tool to do this work or i should learn opengl?
thx~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200193/build-3d-environment/) by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-12-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-30**:
opengl is definitely not the right direction to go in. You may want to look at the gazebo world editor.

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2014-12-30**:
@ahendrix thank you very much ! by the way where i can find "gazebo world editor" are there some tutorials exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [Gazebo Tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials), in particular the [world-building tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=build_world).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2014-12-30**:
@ahendrix thank!